# Merging Group by and order by in Oracle

Tags: oracle, group-by, sql-order-by

This is what I have and below what I want to do. `d`. is a table, and `act` is a view that consists of about 50 combined tables:

```
SELECT d.extensionaspect1                 AS "Exception ID", 
       d.causedat                         AS "Date",
       max(act.date_)                     AS "Causedate",
       act.prodsteppath                   AS "Production Step", 
       --I'm calling other selections on d, but i'm not going to incude
       --them for the sake of clarity

FROM   pasx.deviationevent d,
       pasx.vtemp_prodsteppath act
       --There's more here, but I'm not going to include them for the sake of clarity

WHERE  act.date_ < d.causedat
       --as before, there's a large amount of AND clauses here that make
       --sure that I get the timestamps I want. This is a pretty complex query

GROUP BY d.causedat,
ORDER BY d.extensionaspect1;
```

Running like this gives me ORA-00936; missing expression. I'm very new at this, so I'm probably fundamentally misunderstanding how to use `select max(act.date_)` and use it to find the timestamp that occurred just before `d.causedate`. `act.date_` contains all the possible timestamps that could lead to throwing an exception, but only the one before the timestamps in d.causedat are relevant to me.

`vtemp_prodsteppath` is a view and contains no order or group by's. How do I join these two tables (`d` and `act`) together? What expression am I missing?

Comment: To clarify further: act is a combined union of nearly 50 tables.

Comment: If you only group by causedat, you need to apply an aggregation function on extensionaspect1 in order to get one value per group.
Also, there is an extra comma after the group by that shouldn't be there.

Comment: Oops! I've removed the comma from my script. A stupid oversight. What do you mean by aggregation function? a DISTINCT or UNIQUE selection, or something more elaborate?

Comment: For example, use MAX(d.extensionaspect1), both in the select list and the order by clause.

Comment: I've added all of the selected attributes into the group by statement, and the script now runs, but it doesn't anneal the max(act.date_) to the d.causedat properly. Do i have to connect the two with a seperate statement in order by? Is that what you refer to?

Comment: In this case, it's listing way too many (like, at least 20+) rows for just one ID, though that may not directy have anything to do with your explanation. Perhaps that is something I should work on myself.